# Cucumber Ruby - Cucumber Expressions

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Trying out some new things in Cucumber Ruby, and I came across their Cucumber Expressions.

I've tried registering parameters:

```
require 'cucumber/cucumber_expressions/parameter_type'
require 'cucumber/cucumber_expressions/parameter_type_registry'

Cucumber::CucumberExpressions::ParameterTypeRegistry.new.define_parameter_type(Cucumber::CucumberExpressions::ParameterType.new(
    'optional_not',
    String,
    /n't| not|/,
    lambda {|s| String.new(s)}
))

Cucumber::CucumberExpressions::ParameterTypeRegistry.new.define_parameter_type(Cucumber::CucumberExpressions::ParameterType.new(
    'string_in_double_quotes',
    String,
    /"[^"]*"/,
    lambda {|s| String.new(s)}
))
```

But when I have a step definition such as:

```
Given "{string_in_double_quotes} does{optional_not} work" do |thing, invert|
   invert = invert.gsub(' ', '')
   if invert == 'n\'t' or invert == 'not'
      # Something here
   else
      # Something here
   end
end
```

It does not match `Given "the expression" does work` or `Given "the expression" does not work` - which it should, and simply comes back with a step snippet

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Turns out that the basic "int" cucumber expression is not working either, and that should be built in.

```
Given "I want {int} potatoes" do |number|
 puts "#{number} potatoes"
end
```

Does not match `And I want 7 potatoes`, as an example.

Using:

- cucumber v3.0.0.pre.1
- cucumber-expressions v3.0.0
- ruby v2.4.1

Comment: Cucumber expressions might not actually be implemented yet for Ruby. The [issue for adding support](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1002) is still in the open state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cucumber expressions are available from v3.0.0 (see: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1002#issuecomment-332734877). However, adding a custom parameter type seems to be undocumented at the moment and I had to dig quite a bit to find out how to do it (see the [`Cucumber::Glue::Dsl` class](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/08fbcc9a70d5efea76b6b435267a81959d9f7da2/lib/cucumber/glue/dsl.rb)).

In my case I wanted to add a `date` parameter type to match the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, so I created a new file `parameter_types.rb` in the `support` directory (I'm using Cucumber to test a Rails application) with the following content:

```
ParameterType name:             'date',
              type:             Date,
              regexp:           /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/,
              transformer:      ->(str) { Date.parse(str) },
              use_for_snippets: true
```

`ParameterType` is a method like `After`, `Before`, etc. that you can use to define hooks. You can add more parameter types by appending them to the same file.

Comment: Documentation is now available here: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration. The rendering for Ruby was broken, but was fixed in https://github.com/cucumber/docs.cucumber.io/pull/530